# Complex C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am used to making JavaScript objects like below but what would be the fastest way of doing the same with C#? It is just static data that will be serialized for a post that will not change. In the past with C# I would create classes and lists for everything but in this scenario I just need to send some practice data. Any help would be appreciated

```
            var data = {
                "dealer": {
                    "keyId": "vfase32sd",  
                     "name": "mark"
                },
                "seller": [
                    {
                        "email": "email@email.com",
                        "active":false
                    }
                ],
                "state": [
                    "TN",
                    "TX"
                ]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic typing feature of C#

```
var data = new 
{
    dealer = new 
    {
        keyId = "vfase32sd", 
        name =  "mark",
    },
    seller = new[] 
    {
        new 
        {
            email = "email@email.com",
            active = false
        }
    },
    state = new [] 
    {
        "TN",
        "TX"
    }
};
```

Comment: This is exact copy of other answer!

Answer (score 9):

See [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

> **Object initializer with Anonymous types**
>
> Although object initializers can be used in any context, they are especially useful in
> LINQ query expressions. Query expressions make frequent use of
> anonymous types, which can only be initialized by using an object
> initializer, as shown in the following declaration.

```
var pet = new { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

For example:

```
var data = new
{
    dealer = new
    {
        keyId = "vfase32sd",
        name = "mark"
    },
    seller = new[] {
        new {
            email= "email@email.com",
            active= false
        }
    },
    state = new[]{
        "TN",
        "TX"
    }
};
```

The rule for converting that js object to c# object is simple:

- `"x":` will be `x=`
- `{}` will be `new {}`
- `[]` will be `new []{}`
- Values remain untouched

Comment: Can you reproduce with my example. Object within object and array within object, object within array, etc

Comment: Perfection. Thank You